# ¿Una funcion trigger puede recoger parámetros de la linea de su disparador?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Estoy intentando recoger el valor de id_tarea que dispara el trigger y usarlo luego en al funcion trigger de la siguiente manera. He añadido una columna id_tarea a imputa_pendiente y a imputa para que cuando se muevan las lineas al introducir una tarea con id_secci=6 inserte el id_tarea que lo a provocado en imputa_pendiente y en imputa, para luego poder hacer un deshacer si se elimina esa linea de tareas que provoco el movimiento, volviendo al estado inicial.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trasladar_pendiente_imputado() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE 
id_tarea INTEGER;
BEGIN
id_tarea := NEW.id;
      INSERT INTO pro.imputa (id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, id_proyecto, importe, observaciones, id_tarea)
       SELECT id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, NEW.id_proyecto, importe, observaciones, id_tarea 
       FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = NEW.id_proyecto AND id_tarea = NEW.id;

      DELETE FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = NEW.id_proyecto AND id_tarea = NEW.id;
      RETURN NULL;
    END;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    CREATE TRIGGER trasladar_pendiente 
      AFTER INSERT ON tar.tarea 
      FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.id_secci = 6) EXECUTE PROCEDURE trasladar_pendiente_imputado(id);
```

De la misma forma, hacer el "deshacer" pero con before delete, para que vuelvan las lineas movidas a su sitio original.

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION destrasladar_pendiente_imputado() RETURNS trigger AS $$
   DECLARE 
id_tarea INTEGER;
BEGIN
id_tarea := NEW.id;
          INSERT INTO pro.imputa_pendiente (id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, id_proyecto, importe, observaciones, id_tarea)
           SELECT id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, NEW.id_proyecto, importe, observaciones, id_tarea 
           FROM pro.imputa WHERE id_proyecto = NEW.id_proyecto AND id_tarea = NEW.id;

          DELETE FROM pro.imputa WHERE id_proyecto = NEW.id_proyecto AND id_tarea = NEW.id;
          RETURN NULL;
        END;

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
        CREATE TRIGGER destrasladar_pendiente 
          BEFORE DELETE ON tar.tarea 
          FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.id_secci = 6) EXECUTE PROCEDURE trasladar_pendiente_imputado(id);
```

Pero esta mal, ya que em dice error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "id_tarea" is ambiguous
LINE 2: ...te_fecha, NEW.id_proyecto, importe, observaciones, id_tarea 
                                                              ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO pro.imputa (id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, id_proyecto, importe, observaciones, id_tarea)
   SELECT id, insert_user_id, insert_fecha, update_user_id, update_fecha, NEW.id_proyecto, importe, observaciones, id_tarea 
   FROM pro.imputa_pendiente WHERE id_proyecto = NEW.id_proyecto AND id_tarea = NEW.id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function trasladar_pendiente_imputado() line 6 at SQL statement
```

He probado con tg_argv[0] para ver de coger le id de la tarea en id_tarea pero tampoco me funciona, me dice que uno es INTEGER y el otro TEXT..

Estoy bastante perdido. gracias por vuestra paciencia.

Comment: Cuando insertas en `tar.tarea` le pasas el `id_tarea` tomándolo de `pro.imputa_pendiente` o es un campo autogenerado? La estructura de la tabla de tareas tiene `id_tarea` como llave primaria y muchas tareas pueden tener el mismo `id_proyecto` ?

Comment: Tar.tarea es independiente de imputa_pendiente y de imputa, solo se tiene en cuenta que la nueva linea de tareas tenga id_secci=6, para que mueva las lineas de imputapendiente de ese id_proyecto generado al crear la linea de tareas. Por ahora no se como pasarle el id_ de la tarea a las tablas imputa_pendiente y imputa.. pero me hace falta para hacer el deshacer correctamente.

Comment: Para resumir, en imputa_pendiente pueden haber lineas inicialmente. las acciones sobre las lineas de imputa_pendiete y imputa, se realizan al insertar o eliminar una linea con id_secci=6 en tar.tareas.

Comment: La problematica la tengo al no saber como recoger el valor id de tar.tarea cuando se lanza el disparador, para poder almacenar en imputa_pendiente y en imputa, el id_tarea que haya provocado su movimiento. De esta manera, en el caso de eliminar la linea insertada en tareas, vuelvan las lineas que se movieron al crear esa tarea de nuevo desde imputa a imputa_pendiente, sin que afecten al resto de lineas que pueden tener o no ese id_proyecto.Por eso no lo puedo controlar todo desde id_proyecto, puesto que pueden haber lineas anteriores de ese id_proyecto, y no seria correcto moverlas o borrarlas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente no veo cuál es el problema que tienes actualmente. Básicamente lo que deseas hacer es insertar es un valor nuevo (que se encuentra en la tabla tareas) a la tabla imputa_pendiente cada vez que se ejecute el trigger.

PostgreSQL no te permitirá el uso de parámetros en una función que retorna trigger, ya que puedes acceder a ellos a través de variables que el sistema pasa automáticamente a la función (TG_ARGV o TG_NARGS). Ten en cuenta que esto no descarta que puedas declarar argumentos para la llamada de la función únicamente en la declaración del trigger.

Desde la misma función, cada vez que se ejecuta el trigger, puedes acceder a todos los valores que se insertaron en la tabla usando NEW.nombre_de_la_columna, donde NEW. indica el nuevo valor que se ha insertado y nombre_de_la_columna es el nombre de la columna que quieres referenciar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Igual no es problema, pero no se como actuar. La duda surge cuando me lo planteo el "deshacer" ya que inicialmente puede ser que hayan lineas existentes en imputa_pendiente pertenecientes a ese id_proyecto pero movidas por otra inserción desde id_tarea, y si yo después, de copiar las lineas de imputa_pendiente a imputa al insertar en tarea un nuevo registro, necesitaría en imputa_pendiente y en imputa, una columna adicional que me almacenara el id_tarea que a provocado su movimiento, para así al borrar esa linea, que vuelvan a imputa_pendiente las lineas

Comment: que se movieron al hacer la inserción en su día. Había pensado eso, "recoger" el id_tarea que provoca el movimiento inicial de imputa_pendiente a imputa y almacenarlo en imputa_pendiente, que se copie con el movimiento de la linea a imputa, y así en caso de borrar ese id_tarea, hacer select a imputa con ese id_proyecto y id_tarea y deshacer el movimiento inicial pasándolas a imputa_pendiente de nuevo.

Comment: Nada de la manera que te puse, no lo consigo, no se como hacerme con id_tarea.

Comment: Antes de nada muchisimas gracias por vuestra ayuda, ya tengo solucionado el problema, no se porque en pruebas anteriores no era capaz de recoger el id de tarea, pero a sido tan simple como usar un NEW.id.

De nuevo muchas gracias y disculpar mi torpeza.

Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda.  Si pudiera publicar expondria la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Y cómo sabes a qué registro de `imputa_pendiente` asociar ese `id` cuando se insertan X tareas para la sección 6 y el proyecto 10, por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

A priori **no tienes un campo `id_tarea` en `imputa_pendiente`** que permita relacionar un registro recién insertado en `tarea` con el correspondiente registro que debiera salir de `imputa_pendiente`.

A la inversa, si al insertar una tarea insertas un registro en `imputa` que contenga como `id_tarea` el `id` de la tarea insertada, sí es trivial saber qué tarea debe salir de `imputa` y volver a `imputa_pendiente`.

**El único workaround que se me ocurre es el flujo sea:**

- Si borro un registro de `imputa_pendiente` y ese registro es de la sección 6, lo inserto en `tarea` **usando el mismo `id` del registro a borrar**, y lo mismo en `imputa`. Luego lo elimino de `imputa_pendiente`
- Si no es de la sección 6, lo borro sin más o bien no hago nada (retorno NULL en el trigger).
- Si borro un registro en `tarea` lo borro de `imputa` (WHERE `imputa.id_tarea` = `OLD.id`) y lo vuelvo a insertar en `imputa_pendiente`.

El truco en este caso sería que `tarea` no tuviese un `id` autogenerado sino que siempre lo obtuviera de `imputa_pendiente`. Eso, y que en realidad la operación no sea

1. Insertar en `tarea`
2. Lo cual

   - Inserta en `imputa`
   - Elimina de `imputa_pendiente`

Sino:

1. Remover de `imputa_pendiente`
2. Lo cual

   - Inserta en `tarea`
   - Inserta en `imputa`
   - Completa la eliminación de `imputa_pendiente`

En este escenario, el `id` de la tabla `tarea` viene del `id` de `imputa_pendiente` y, como dije, no es autogenerado. Esa sería la manera de crear la relación entre ambas tablas.

Entonces tienes:

imputa_pendiente:

```
id (autogenerado) | id_secci
----------------------------
       1          |    4
       2          |    6
       3          |    4
       4          |    6
       5          |    4
       6          |    5
```

tarea:

```
id (viene de imputa_pendiente) | id_secci
-----------------------------------------
       7                       |    6
       8                       |    6
```

imputa:

```
id (autogenerado) | id_secci | id_tarea
---------------------------------------
       1          |    6     |     7
       2          |    6     |     8
```

**Si borras el registro 2 de `imputa_pendiente` las tablas quedan:**

imputa_pendiente (ya no tiene el registro 2)

```
id (autogenerado) | id_secci
----------------------------
       1          |    4
       3          |    4
       4          |    6
       5          |    4
       6          |    5
```

tarea (se insertó el registro 2 con id explícito)

```
id (viene de imputa_pendiente) | id_secci
-----------------------------------------
       7                       |    6
       8                       |    6
       2                       |    6
```

imputa (se insertó un registro con `id_tarea` = 2)

```
id (autogenerado) | id_secci | id_tarea
---------------------------------------
       1          |    6     |     7
       2          |    6     |     8
       3          |    6     |     2
```

Y finalmente si borras el registro 8 de `tarea` las tablas quedan:

imputa_pendiente (volvió el registro con `id` = 8)

```
id (autogenerado) | id_secci
----------------------------
       1          |    4
       3          |    4
       4          |    6
       5          |    4
       6          |    5
       8          |    6
```

tarea:  (se eliminó el registro con `id` = 8)

```
id (viene de imputa_pendiente) | id_secci
-----------------------------------------
       7                       |    6
       2                       |    6
```

imputa: (se eliminó el registro con `id_tarea` = 8)

```
id (autogenerado) | id_secci | id_tarea
---------------------------------------
       1          |    6     |     7
       3          |    6     |     2
```

Si en cambio yo borrase de `imputa_pendiente` un registro con otra `id_secci` no pasaría nada en las otras dos tablas.

La definición de los triggers sería entonces:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trasladar_pendiente_imputado()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.id_secci=6 THEN
        INSERT INTO tarea (id, id_secci) VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.id_secci);
        INSERT INTO imputa (id_secci, id_tarea) VALUES (OLD.id_secci, OLD.id);
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
    RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
RESET ROLE;

CREATE TRIGGER trasladar_pendiente
BEFORE DELETE ON imputa_pendiente
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trasladar_pendiente_imputado();
```

Y

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION destrasladar_pendiente_imputado()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO imputa_pendiente (id, id_secci) VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.id_secci);
    DELETE FROM imputa WHERE id_tarea = OLD.id;
    RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
RESET ROLE;


CREATE TRIGGER destrasladar_pendiente
BEFORE DELETE ON tarea
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE destrasladar_pendiente_imputado();
```

Como ves, nunca inserto directo en `id_tarea` porque de hacerlo no conocería de que registro en `imputa_pendiente` proviene. La inserción debe producirse indirectamente al borrar en `imputa_pendiente`

Al insertar de vuelta un registro en `imputa_pendiente` no tengo problemas con el id autogenerado porque inserto un id que ya estuvo alguna vez en `imputa_pendiente` y la secuencia se mantiene en la última inserción implícita.

Comment: Claro, pero ese campo puede ser compartido en muchos registros en las tres tablas. Sólo tienes que añadir ese campo a los procedimientos que te mostré y a las tablas de ejemplo. Pero de todos modos el id del proyecto no identifica un registro en ninguna de las tablas, es sólo un dato más como podría serlo el `id_secci`

Comment: Sí, pero no tienes un `id_tarea` en `imputa_pendiente`, por eso no puedes trabajar únicamente con la tabla de tareas. Lo que te propuse es un workaround en donde `tarea` toma su `id` de `imputa_pendiente`, en vez de ser un serial. Cualquier otro camino que empiece con una inserción directa en `id_tarea` pierde la relación con `imputa_pendiente` (a menos que hicieras la inserción en `id_tarea` específicando tú mismo un `id` presente en `imputa_pendiente`)

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo así, entonces tienes que tener predefinido el `id_tarea` en la tabla `imputa_pendiente` y al insertar en `tarea` usar ese valor en vez de un id autogenerado. No parece muy práctico y no tiene integridad referencial

Comment: Por eso te digo: no puedes insertar un campo en `tarea` con un `id` autogenerado, porque `imputa_pendiente` no tiene como adivinar cuál fue ese `id`. El `id` de la tabla `tarea` debiese ser el mismo `id` que se borrará de `imputa_pendiente` y la única manera de conocer ese ID es empezar el proceso borrando de `imputa_pendiente`. Todo esto partiendo de la base que Puedes insertar N tareas con el mismo  `id_proyecto` luego ¿Cómo sabes qué imputas debes mover de una tabla a la otra?

Comment: Con eso `imputa` conoce el valor de `id_tarea` pero `imputa_pendiente` no lo conoce. No sabes qué registros borrar de `imputa_pendiente` y no podrías echarlos atrás en forma atómica. Sólo podrías mover todo lo que tenga el mismo `id_proyecto` de ida y de vuelta, así sea uno o veinte registros